# Kubeless function invoke error

Tags: kubernetes, serverless-framework, kubeless

Im having trouble invoking functions using kubeless. 
Here is the function spec

```
---
apiVersion: kubeless.io/v1beta1
kind: Function
metadata:
  name: smk
  namespace: smktest
spec:
  handler: hello.handler
  runtime: python2.7
  function: |
      import json
      def handler():
              return "hello world"
  deployment:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
             - env:
               - name: FOO
                 value: bar
               name: "smk-deployment"
               resources:
                 limits:
                   cpu: 100m
                   memory: 100Mi
                 requests:
                   cpu: 100m
                   memory: 100Mi
```

When I try to call the function as below,

```
kubeless function call smk
```

I get

`FATA[0000] Unable to find the service for smk`

Two part question

1. How do I expose my function as  a service
2. How do I specify Environment variables needed by this function ? 
   Thank you

***Update***
Running kubeless function ls --namespace=smktest yields below

```
NAME    NAMESPACE   HANDLER         RUNTIME     DEPENDENCIES    STATUS
smk     smktest     hello.handler   python2.7                   MISSING: Check controller logs
```

Next I tried `kubectl logs -n kubeless -l kubeless=controller` there's tons of error logs but I don't see anything specific to this function

Comment: What is the output of `kubeless function ls` (as opposed to `kubectl get function`)?

Answer (score 1):

> When I try to call the function as below,
>
> `kubeless function call smk`
>
> I get
>
> `FATA[0000] Unable to find the service for smk`
>
> Running `kubeless function ls --namespace=smktest`

Then surely you would need to include the `--namespace=smktest` in your invocation command, too:

```
kubeless function call --namespace=smktest smk
```

---

> How do I specify Environment variables needed by this function ? Thank you

As best I can tell, there seems to be two approaches in use:

- [Provide a `Deployment` template](https://github.com/kubeless/kubeless/blob/v0.6.0/pkg/apis/kubeless/v1beta1/function.go#L45), which the [`function controller` appears to merge](https://github.com/kubeless/kubeless/blob/v0.6.0/pkg/controller/function_controller.go#L311) but as far as I know `container: image:` is required in a `Deployment`, so you'd have to specify one in order to get access to its `env:` declaration
- Otherwise "cheat" and use the `Pod`s `ServiceAccount` token to [request cluster resources manually](https://github.com/kubeless/functions/blob/d80825f1d21e2686a1f817a45d333729a360da8a/incubator/slack/bot.py#L11) which might include a `ConfigMap`, `Secret`, or even resolving your own `kubeless.io/function` manifest and pulling something out of its annotations or similar